# testing for ENTER key being pressed to submit a form

Tags: jquery

This is driving me mad. I'm building a page to search wikipedia, so I have a simple search form. 
I want to capture the user pressing enter on the keyboard rather than clicking the search button with the mouse, and I have tried EVERYTHING (I think) suggested in answers to people with the same query (ie capturing the enter key), and not a single thing works. Not one. What am I doing wrong, and what code should I use? 
Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<form id="theForm" class="searchForm centercontent">
<input type="search" name="search" value="" id="searchTerm" placeholder="search Wikipedia">
<button type="button" name="searchButton" id="btnSearch"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

I have tried all of these, separately (some of these don't make sense, but I'm desperate)

```
$('#searchTerm').keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$('.searchTerm').keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$(document).keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$('.searchForm').keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$(form).keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$('#searchForm').keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$(input).keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$('.search').keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
$('#search').keypress(function(e) {if (e.which == 13) {alert('key pressed');}});
```

Comment: Could you expand on _why_ you're wanting to detect `Enter` vs a mouse click (vs other ways to submit a form)? This feels slightly like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as it's currently written.

Comment: Because I'm learning, or trying to, and it seemed a sensible thing to do to, in my very limited knowledge. Also because the way I approach coding is to get a tiny little bit to work first, and then the next tiny little bit and so on. What I want is buiding a search page for Wikipedia, and I want to understand every bit of code on that page, as a learning thing. So really, I have to build it myself, unless you can point me to some code that is already written and every line of code commented on in a way that a beginner like myself can understand. Hope that makes sense... :-)

Comment: That makes sense. Generally what you're looking for is what @Ess already addresses by detecting a form _submit_, not specifically _Enter_ being pressed (the use case for wanting to specifically detect _Enter submitting the form_ is pretty small). But as something to play around with and learn from, then go crazy. To clarify a few of your selectors, if you do `$('#thing')` that will select an element with `id="thing"`, vs `$('.thing')` selects an element with `class="thing"`. To select the form element, the following would be valid: `$('form')` or `$('#theForm')` or `$('.searchForm')`.

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more info on selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the button type to submit

```
<button type="submit" name="searchButton" id="btnSearch"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
```

this way you don't need to check for Enter key press, it will automatically activate

Comment: ahhh, OK. Thanks! But then how do I catch that in the code? At the moment, I'm using " $("#btnSearch").on("click", function() {.. (do stuff)" What do I replace that with?

Comment: `$('#theForm').on('submit', function(event) { ... });` https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: `$('form.searchForm').submit(()=>{ /* here goes your code */ })`

Comment: Please, if the answer helped you make it right and vote it so when other comes and ask the same question they'll find the right answer. Good luck.

Comment: actually, i've just tried it, and now neither the enter key or the mouse click work, and this is something I have been working on for DAYS (I'm a learner). But I'm sure the answer will be useful to other people. I did try to upvote it, but got a message saying that this would be recorded but not displayed, because I'm too new. So... sorry... :-( And thank you!

Comment: OK, I 've sorted out the problem.. all good now! So thank you! And to anybody who finds this in the future, I can confirm that the answer definitely worked. :-)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that @Emma.

Comment: @Emma don't forget that [you can accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)